# text search in muse to find a URL

Tags: search, text, muse

I wonder if anyone can point me in the right direction.
I want my Muse website visitors to be able to search a text list in order to find a specific hyperlink.

Simple (I hope) - text entered in a box will return the appropriate URL

(Cannot post examples)

I just cannot find a way of doing this in muse.
Nor can I find a widget to do it

Thanks

Nick

Comment: Try to do something by yourself and post more specific questions to increase the chances of getting an answer.

Comment: I should probably use Dreamweaver I guess ...